# How to fix errors in php form submission?

Tags: php, forms, validation

as a newbie in PHP language I've setup a php contact form (contact.php) with html coding alongwith the Javascript validation code. Upon completion all the things it is not getting submitted and coming to my given email id. Really, I couldn't figure out the code where the problem has occured. Would you please check these below codes and help me to fix this out?

```
<?php

// Set email variables
$email_to = 'contact@mycompany.com';
$email_subject = 'New Contact Form Submission';

/* Gathering Data Variables */

    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $ipaddress = $_POST['ipaddress'];

    $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Full Name: $fullname <br>
Email: $email <br>
Phone: $phone <br>
Country: $country <br>
Message: $message <br>
Submitted By IP: $ipaddress <br>
EOD;

    $headers = "From: $fullname\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body,
$headers);

// Set required fields
$required_fields = array('fullname','email','country','message');

// set error messages
$error_messages = array(
    'fullname' => 'Please enter Your Name to proceed.',
    'email' => 'Please enter a valid Email Address to contact.',
    'country' => 'Please enter your country of residence.',
    'message' => 'Please enter your message.'
);

// Set form status
$form_complete = FALSE;

// configure validation array
$validation = array();

// check form submittal
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    // Sanitise POST array
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) $_POST[$key] = remove_email_injection(trim($value));

    // Loop into required fields and make sure they match our needs
    foreach($required_fields as $field) {       
        // the field has been submitted?
        if(!array_key_exists($field, $_POST)) array_push($validation, $field);

        // check there is information in the field?
        if($_POST[$field] == '') array_push($validation, $field);

        // validate the email address supplied
        if($field == 'email') if(!validate_email_address($_POST[$field])) array_push($validation, $field);
    }

    // basic validation result
    if(count($validation) == 0) {
        // Prepare our content string
        $email_content = 'Contact Form Submission Received: ' . "\n\n";

        // simple email content
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if($key != 'submit') $email_content .= $key . ': ' . $value . "\n";
        }

        // if validation passed ok then send the email
        mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_content);

        // Update form switch
        $form_complete = TRUE;
    }
}

function validate_email_address($email = FALSE) {
    return (preg_match('/^[^@\s]+@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}$/i', $email))? TRUE : FALSE;
}

function remove_email_injection($field = FALSE) {
   return (str_ireplace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d", "Content-Type:", "bcc:","to:","cc:"), '', $field));
}

?>
```

**Form Start**

```
<?php if($form_complete === FALSE): ?>
                                        <form name="contact_form" method="post" id="contact_form" action="contacts.php" onsubmit="return defaultagree(this)"><table width="430" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left"><table width="430" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle" align="right" width="130" class="offerformtext"><span>*</span> Name:</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" width="300" class="mbox"><input name="fullname" id="fullname" type="text" class="offer_input_box" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['fullname'])? $_POST['fullname'] : ''; ?>" /><?php if(in_array('fullname', $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['fullname']; ?></span><?php endif; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left"><table width="430" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle" align="right" width="130" class="offerformtext"><span>*</span> Email:</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" width="300" class="mbox"><input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="offer_input_box" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email'])? $_POST['email'] : ''; ?>" /><?php if(in_array('email', $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['email']; ?></span><?php endif; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left"><table width="430" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle" align="right" width="130" class="offerformtext">Phone:</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" width="300"><input name="phone" id="phone" type="text" value="" class="offer_input_box" /></td>
  </tr>
</table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left"><table width="430" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle" align="right" width="130" class="offerformtext"><span>*</span> Country:</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" width="300" class="mbox"><input name="country" id="country" type="text" class="offer_input_box" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['country'])? $_POST['country'] : ''; ?>" /></textarea><?php if(in_array('country', $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['country']; ?></span><?php endif; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left"><table width="430" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="right" width="130" class="offerformtext"><span>*</span> Message:</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" width="300" class="mmbox"><textarea name="message" id="message" class="offer_message_box" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['message'])? $_POST['message'] : ''; ?>" /></textarea><?php if(in_array('message', $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['message']; ?></span><?php endif; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="bottom" align="center" class="subdown"><input name="submit" type="Submit" class="offer_submit_button" value=""/><br /><br /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="ipaddress" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php else: ?>
                                                <h2 style="font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:24px; color:#6d6d6d; font-weight:bold;">Contact Form Successfully Submitted</h2>
<p style="font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:18px; color:#255E67; margin-left:25px; margin-top:15px;">Thank you for your get in touch with us! We would get back to you regarding this information soon.</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout('ourRedirect()', 8000)
function ourRedirect(){
    location.href='contacts.php'
}
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
                                    <script>
document.forms.contact_form.agreecheck.checked=false
</script>
```

Form End

These are the codes that I've used, Please please help me regarding this matter. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the control reach your `mail()` line of code?

Comment: Thanks Hanky, but nothing is going to my email. Please help.

Comment: @Sumu The `$webMaster` variable is not set anywhere, so of course it doesn't know where to send it. `it=form_message` ;-) You could also use `amigura's` answer below which makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

i have slightly changed your code. You seem to be constructing email before validating it.
you can have all code in one file rather than two.

```
<?php

  // Set email variables
$email_to = 'contact@mycompany.com';
$email_subject = 'New Contact Form Submission';
$ipaddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// Set required fields
$required_fields = array('fullname','email','country','message');

// set error messages
$error_messages = array(
    'fullname' => 'Please enter Your Name to proceed.',
    'email' => 'Please enter a valid Email Address to contact.',
    'country' => 'Please enter your country of residence.',
    'message' => 'Please enter your message.'
);



// check form submittal
if(!empty($_POST)) {


// Sanitise POST array
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){ 

if($key=="fullname"){$fullname=str_replace( '[at]','@', $value);}
if($key=="country"){$country=str_replace( '[at]','@', $value);}
if($key=="message"){$message=str_replace( '[at]','@', $value);}
if($key=="phone"){$phone=str_replace( '[at]','@', $value);}

if($key=="email"){
if(!filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { $error_out[$key]=$error_messages[$key];} else{$email=$value;}
   }

// check required fields
        if(in_array($key, $required_fields) and empty($value))
        {
             $error_out[$key]=$error_messages[$key]; // errors for required
        }

if($key=="amigura"){$amigura='';}else{$amigura='';}

}

$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Full Name: $fullname <br>
Email: $email <br>
Phone: $phone <br>
Country: $country <br>
Message: $message <br>
Submitted By IP: $ipaddress <br>
EOD;

//echo $body;   

    // send mail
    if(!$error_out){

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $fullname <$email> \r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8 \r\n";

    if(mail($email_to, $emailSubject, $body,$headers)){$form_complete='sendme';}

        }
        else
        {$form_complete='';}

}


?>

<?php if($form_complete != 'sendme'): ?>
                                        <form name="contact_form" method="post" id="contact_form" action="" onsubmit="return defaultagree(this)"><table width="430" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left"><table width="430" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle" align="right" width="130" class="offerformtext"><span>*</span> Name:</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" width="300" class="mbox"><input name="fullname" id="fullname" type="text" class="offer_input_box" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['fullname'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>" /><?php if($error_out['fullname']): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_out['fullname']; ?></span><?php endif; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left"><table width="430" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle" align="right" width="130" class="offerformtext"><span>*</span> Email:</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" width="300" class="mbox"><input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="offer_input_box" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $_POST['email'] , ENT_QUOTES); ?>" /><?php if($error_out['email']): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_out['email']; ?></span><?php endif; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left"><table width="430" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle" align="right" width="130" class="offerformtext">Phone:</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" width="300"><input name="phone" id="phone" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $_POST['phone'] , ENT_QUOTES); ?>" class="offer_input_box" /></td>
  </tr>
</table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left"><table width="430" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle" align="right" width="130" class="offerformtext"><span>*</span> Country:</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" width="300" class="mbox"><input name="country" id="country" type="text" class="offer_input_box" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $_POST['country'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>" /></textarea><?php if($error_out['country']): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_out['country']; ?></span><?php endif; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left"><table width="430" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="right" width="130" class="offerformtext"><span>*</span> Message:</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" width="300" class="mmbox"><textarea name="message" id="message" class="offer_message_box" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>" /></textarea><?php if($error_out['message']): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_out['message']; ?></span><?php endif; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="bottom" align="center" class="subdown"><input name="submit" type="Submit" class="offer_submit_button" value=""/><br /><br /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php else: ?>
                                                <h2 style="font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:24px; color:#6d6d6d; font-weight:bold;">Contact Form Successfully Submitted</h2>
<p style="font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:18px; color:#255E67; margin-left:25px; margin-top:15px;">Thank you for your get in touch with us! We would get back to you regarding this information soon.</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout('ourRedirect()', 8000)
function ourRedirect(){
    location.href='contacts.php'
}
</script>
<?php endif; ?>

<script>
//document.forms.contact_form.agreecheck.checked=false
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @amigura, I've changed the $webmaster to $email_to, and the email is coming but it is not redirecting to the successful message page, and even a blank form is submitting when I clicking on the submitting button without filling up any data into the fields. Please help.

Comment: Thank you amigura, now I'm receiving the email but in the "From" field it is not showing the email (of the form submitter), instead it is showing my server default email like "example@abcd.globedns.com. How can I change that? Thank you.

Comment: @Sumu have a look at example 2 [php mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: Thank you so much amigura for your kind assistance. Now all are working fine, but still I've a problem regarding the "Security Code". I mean for the security code I've used the below-mentioned code, but yet I can pass the captcha by writing the wrong code or anything. I've tried to put in several places but still it is not validating. Would please help me about this? I mean where I'd put this code in the contact.php file? The code is given below:

Comment: i see no captcha code but i did forget to uncomment at bottom `document.forms.contact_form.agreecheck.checked=false` if that is it

Comment: Yes @amigura, you are right there were no captcha code, I added that later, but for putting in the wrong place it is not working. And by the way, I removed the comment from the line that you mentioned. session_start();

if(($_SESSION['security_code'] == $_POST['security_code']) && (!empty($_SESSION['security_code'])) ) 
{ unset($_SESSION['security_code']);

} else {
   echo "Oops! You entered the wrong security code";
}

Comment: looks ok but you don't really need brackets `session_start();if($_SESSION['security_code'] == $_POST['security_code'] && !empty($_SESSION['security_code']) ) { good code } else { bad code }` debug echo `s='.$_SESSION['security_code'].' p='.$_POST['security_code'];`